# Datable not working in django/bootstrap 4

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, datatables

**Goal:**
I am using django and bootstrap. I would like to use datatable jquery plugin in my bootstrap table.

**Issues:**
The table in my html stay the same and doesn`t use the datatable plugin

**What Ive done to resolve this issue?**  I`ve added the two lines in my base.html file

**base.html**

```
<!-- Datatable -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

and the javascript code as well:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
    });
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

My table is named dtBasicExample in my html file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-20">      
            <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-hover">
```

Is there anything I need to add in django to make it work?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're including the libraries and calling .DataTable() in a wrong order.

The page should be like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<head>

<body>
    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-hover">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

**Note:**

- I'm including jQuery before including datatables lib
- I'm calling the .DataTable method after the include of datatables lib

Comment: Thank you, it works this way. The only thing is that I thought that I could put this code in the base.html and this could could works for every table in my project called dtBasicExample. I`ll copy the script in each html page at the moment.Thanks again